# Node.js script shown in browser instead of html files

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express

Thanks for looking at this question.

My problem is: I have a regular nodejs, socket.io, express script which does work in localhost.
When I try to run in on my webserver on my domain however, using an SSH connection to A2hosting, the index.js file is shown in the browser as plain text, instead of the html files it tells the browser to show.

**Here is the express.js part of my index.js file:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var os = require('os');
http.listen(45123);
var html_dir = './html+css/';
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(html_dir + 'index.html');
});

app.get('/phone', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(html_dir + 'phone.html');
});
app.get('/back.png', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(html_dir + 'back.png');
});
```

**Here is my .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ views/index.js [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:45123/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:45123/$1 [P,L]
DirectoryIndex /views/index.js
```

**This is what it looks like in my browser:**
[image: Screenshot of index.js in browser]

**And this is what my paths look like:**
in the folder public_html, I have the folder views (for example.com/views), as well as my .htaccess file for views. Inside that folder views is the index.js file.

Also after 'starting' my app, the problem still occurs.

I truly hope to have provided enough information for the problem to be solved.
Success trying to solve this
thanks

Comment: This line `DirectoryIndex /views/index.js` tells Apache to serve index.js file when `/` is requested. No js file that is part of node app should be mentioned in htaccess file nor it should be publicly accessible. There's quite a few examples on the web showing how to setup Apache for node.js

Comment: @Molda Thanks for the explanation on htaccess. However, I use a Linux server without root access to apache so that is not an option.